# I am getting esLint no-unused-vars error on cardlist in my React-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Cardlist from './cardList';
import 'tachyons';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {avatars} from './avatars';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Cardlist avatars = {avatars}/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

This is the code for index.js

I don't know how to solve this problem. I am using Atom. I changed cardlist to Cardlist I didn't get any error in terminal but I didn't get the output

Comment: You probably need to setup eslint to underststand JSX syntax.
I recommend to use this lib for that [https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react]

Comment: You should remove space in between `=` like `<Cardlist avatars={avatars}/>`

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work